# Why can't this menu item work?

Tags: vim

I got this in my vimrc:

```
:so menu_format.vim
```

and in menu_format.vim, this:

```
"... other menu items that work
menu Format.nbsp_space <ESC>:%s@ @ @gec<CR> //(the 1st blank is 0xa0, the 2nd is 0x20)
"... other menu items that work
```

On Windows it works (been using it for a while), but on Linux Mint 17 vim gives:

```
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version.
```

I tried `%s@ @ @gec` on command line, it worked, too!

I knew how to fix this: `%s@[\xa0]@ @gec` would do. I just wanted to know why there is such a difference, and it made me doubt the portability of my vim scripts.

BTW, I built vim (7.4.560) on both Linux and Windows with the same configuration, both use the same menu_format.vim.

Comment: Please read `:h E319`. The error is implying that you do not have the compile-time feature for the `:menu` command (Probably `+menu`). Please take a look at `:version` to make sure it is switched on.

Comment: Sorry maybe I was unclear: vim has +menu, other self-made menu items in menu_format.vim work, menu Format.nbsp_space <ESC>:%s@[\xa0]@ @gec<CR> works too.

Comment: That is odd. I do not know why `E319` is being raised in this context. What does `:verbose set encoding?` yield for both of your machines?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you only have the minimal version of Vim named `vim-tiny`; it only provides a minimal vi-compatible implementation. The `E319` implies that the `:menu` command is not available, the `:substitute` does look fine and should work.

To get the full Vim (and graphical GVIM), install the following package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```